# How to get Embed Picture in mp3 file in android?

Tags: android

I want to show album art in my mediaplayer app. I develop it for api7 (2.1). I use getEmbedPicture() method but it gives error and I can't find the error.

What is wrong with it?

```
     retriver.setDataSource(serviceBinder.path+serviceBinder.track);
    try{
        InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(retriver.getEmbeddedPicture());
        if(is==null)
            cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_album);
        else{
            is=new ByteArrayInputStream(retriver.getEmbeddedPicture());
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            cover.setImageBitmap(bMap);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

how can I get embed picture from an mp3 file with android api7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
         MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
         mmr.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
         byte[] artBytes =  mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
         if(artBytes!=null)
           {

             Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(artBytes, 0, artBytes.length);
             bSongImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
         }
         else
         {
             bSongImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.masud));
         }
```

**else used for not having an embedded picture**

Answer (score 0):

[MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) isn't available in API 7. You need to use a library like [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever).